# How to add buildpath options for eclipse from maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Since last summer Eclipse supports a feature where you can suppress the non-important code issues per build path ([described here](http://eclipser-blog.blogspot.nl/2012/03/ignore-optional-compile-problems-is-now.html)).

When you set this option from the GUI I see that this is reflected as follows in the .classpath file of the project.

```
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="target/generated-sources/proto">
            <attributes>
                    <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
            </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

I have an existing Maven based project and I would like to configure it so that when I run
 **mvn eclipse:eclipse**  the .classpath file that is generated contains above option for the buildpaths with the generated source code.

I've examined all of the options of the [eclipse mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) and I've not been able to figure out how to do this.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, neither the [Maven2 Eclipse plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MECLIPSE) (mvn eclipse:eclipse) nor the [Eclipse M2E  plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e) support this feature.

Both projects have open issues/bugs related to this :

- A bug has been filed for it in the [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388541) that includes a patch.
- The Maven2 Eclipse plugin also has an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MECLIPSE-735) on it.